# multiple angular solutions refresh

Tags: angularjs, angular, refresh

I have 2 angular solutions

1. is an angular 4 solution
2. is an angular 1 solution which is located
   under /old.

my base href in the old is set to

```
<base href="/old/">
```

When I go to http://mysolution, the angular 4 solution loads.
When I go to http://mysolution/old, the angular 1 solution loads.

But if I reload my angular 1 solution, it jumps to my angular 2 solution.

Can anyone please help ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using hash location strategy for my routing

I simply added the option hash in my routing module

```
export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES, {useHash: true});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a "catch all route" in your code? Something like:

```
 { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
```

If so, maybe it's parsing the "/old" and redirecting you

Comment: I do, but removing it, does not help.

Comment: Are you hosting it with apache? Maybe you have a rewrite rule for your old and new app and they are conflicting?